# Assign binary value whether a column contains empty list

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to assign a binary value (1 or 0) whether a column contains not empty/empty lists.

For example:

```
Country       Test
Germany        []
Italy         ['pizza']
United Kingdom ['queen', 'king','big']
France        ['Eiffel']
Spain         []

...
```

What I would expect is something like this:

```
Country       Test            Binary
Germany        []               0
Italy         ['pizza']         1
United Kingdom ['queen', 'king','big']    1
France        ['Eiffel']        1
Spain         []                0

...
```

I do not know how to use `np.where` or another to get these results.
I think to check if a column contains an empty list I should do something like this: `df[df['Test'] != '[]']`

Comment: `df['Binary'] = (df['Test'] != []).astype(int)`

Comment: getting this error: ValueError: Lengths must match to compare

Comment: try `df['Binary'] = (df['Test'].neq([])).astype(int)` then

Comment: Unfortunately another error: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'neq'

Comment: Finally, a working solution: `df['Test'].astype(bool).astype(int)`

Comment: thanks Marat. Yes now it works

Comment: `df['Binary'] = (df['Test'].str.len() != 0).astype(int)` worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `str.len`:

```
np.clip(df.Test.str.len(), 0, 1)
#or
(df.Test.str.len()==0).astype(int)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do a simple check for length and based on the value, you can convert it to 0 or 1.

```
df['Binary'] = (df['Test'].str.len() != 0).astype(int)
```

While this is good, the most efficient way to do it was provided by @Marat.

```
df['Binary'] = df['Test'].astype(bool).astype(int)
```

The full code is here:

```
import pandas as pd
c = ['Country','Test']
d = [['Germany',[]],
['Italy',['pizza']],
['United Kingdom', ['queen', 'king','big']],
['France',['Eiffel']],
['Spain',[]]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d,columns=c)
df['Binary'] = df['Test'].astype(bool).astype(int)
print (df)
```

The output of this will be:

```
          Country                Test  Binary
0         Germany                  []       0
1           Italy             [pizza]       1
2  United Kingdom  [queen, king, big]       1
3          France            [Eiffel]       1
4           Spain                  []       0
```